# Azure Cognitives services speech to text recognition of numeric entities as text

Tags: azure, speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

I was wondering if its possible that the c++ sdk of Cognitives services Speech to text to return the numeric entities as text instead of numbers.

Current response 'I want to order 2 Cokes'
Expected response 'I want to order two Cokes'

Of course i can implement a feature to the translation. But i was wondering if its something that the service already provides. Particularly on spanish.

Answer (score 2):

take a look at the sample repository at https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk

especially the file speech_recognition_samples.cpp , function SpeechRecognitionWithLanguageAndUsingDetailedOutputFormat

Enabling ‘detailed output’ will give you the result you want:

```
config->SetOutputFormat(OutputFormat::Detailed);
```

Then you need to look at the detailed output:

```
result->Properties.GetProperty(PropertyId::SpeechServiceResponse_JsonResult)
```

And that would create detailed output like this:

```
{"Duration":35500000,"NBest":[{"Confidence":0.7535948753356934,"Display":"I want to order 2 Cokes.","ITN":"I want to order 2 cokes","Lexical":"i want to order two cokes","MaskedITN":"I want to order 2 cokes"}],"Offset":17000000,"RecognitionStatus":"Success"}
```

The lexical output is probably what you want

Wolfgang